# Installing pl/r pl/python pl/v8 in Ubuntu

Tags: postgis, ubuntu, apt-get, procedural-language

I am trying to find instructions on installing the PostGIS Procedural Languages (PL) for R, Python and V8 as required for the "PostGIS in Action" 2ed. book. I searched on google and couldn't find instructions.

Does anyone know if this can be done using the `apt-get` system without compiling from source?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and a daily built version of the upcoming 16.04 LTS for testing.

Comment: If you're using a daily build, then this is a software engineering issue, not a GIS one.

Comment: @Vince Really? It's **one** of the two versions I am testing. How does that make it not GIS?

Comment: Absolutely. PostGIS isn't even GIS software --It's just a database extension which can be used by GIS packages. You're asking about experimental Linux database configuration -- better to ask the Linux/database folks in an appropriate SE.

Comment: @Vince I'd hardly call using PostGIS on an LTS version of Ubuntu an 'experimental' configuration. PostGIS is a component of the GIS infrastructure, saying it's off-topic would be like saying quesitons about shapefiles are off topic because it's not about software. Also, tinyx, what did you really search for? The top Google result for 'ubuntu plr' is the package for PL/R which is aptly named 'plr.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The upcoming Ubuntu 16.04 LTS seems to have good support for PostGIS and the procedural languages, out of the box. I didn't have to add the UbuntuGIS PPA. PL/R and PL/python can be installed, e.g. with:

```
apt-get install postgresql-plpython3-9.5 postgresql-9.5-plr
```

However, the PL/v8 support seems to be missing in 16.04. The only thing I can find is for postgres 9.4:  `postgresql-9.4-plv8`.

The above also installs the latest PostGIS 2.2 and PostgreSQL 9.5 along the way.